# Slicing and appending lists leaves extra values on the end

Tags: python, list, slice

I want to append the first 80% of the values in two arrays into one new array. I can figure out a work around to this issue but I came across this problem when trying to do it in one line and I'm interested in knowing if it is possible.

```
# I create my two arrays
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]

# Showing what slicing a and b in this way returns
# 4 in this case is equal to 80%
a[:4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
b[:4]
[6, 7, 8, 9]

# Append 80% of b to 80% of a 
a[:4] += b[:4]

# Print a
# There is a 5 at the end which I don't want to be there :(
a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5]
```

I understand that what my one line is doing is telling python to insert 80% of **b**, 80% of the way through **a**, but not actually to only keep 80% of **a**.

Is there a way to do this without then having to remove the last 20% of **a** afterwards?

Comment: Just use: `c = a[:4] + b[:4]`. What you're doing is slice assignment. It assigns to the fourth element the entire slice.

Comment: `c=a.copy()[:4]+b.copy()[:4]`

Comment: Please don't use "80%" to describe what you're doing - it's slicing the first 4 elements and it's only 80% by coincidence, because your lists are 5 items long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're writing is like `a[:4] = a[:4] + b[:4]`, you're leaving the last index of `a` (i.e. `5`), unchanged. You could think of it a bit like an insert (without creating a nested list), i.e.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a.insert(4, b[:4])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, [6, 7, 8, 9], 5]
```

The solution to modify the same list as you want is to assign not just to `a[:4]`, but to the *entire* list:

```
>>> a[:] = a[:4] + b[:4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# I create my two arrays
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]

a=a.copy()[:4]+b.copy()[:4]
# output [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

shallow copy, a reference of object is copied in other object. 
It means that any changes made to a copy of object do reflect in the original objec
 t. In python, this is implemented using “copy()” function.

created a shallow copy of a and b then, i am taking first 4 elements from it and 
 appending b element with a .

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
a[:4] += b[:4]
```

With this equation, you're basically adding the first 4 elements of b[6,7,8,9] to a[1,2,3,4], leaving the last element of a[5] untouched. You can leave out the last index of a[5] by doing

```
c = a[:4] + b[:4]
```